# How to output last and next dates based on GETDATE() in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a database of customers and tickets. The tickets dates range from 2007 to future dates in 2017. I would like to run a query to give me the most recent ticket in the past and the closest date in the future.

My initial query below gives me their first ever ticket and their ticket date furthest away in the future - but I would like something along the lines of:

MAX(eventdate) where (eventdate < getdate())AS LastDate and similarly MIN(eventdate) where (eventdate < getdate())AS NEXTDate but I really don't know how. Presumably it would involve subqueries?

```
SELECT     MAX(Dwh.DimEvents.devEventDate) AS Last_Show, MIN(Dwh.DimEvents.devEventDate) AS First_Show, Dwh.DimClients.dcClientCode, Dwh.DimClients.dcFirstName, Dwh.DimClients.dcLastName
FROM       Dwh.FactTickets LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Dwh.DimClients ON Dwh.DimClients.dcClientGUID = Dwh.FactTickets.ftClientGuid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Dwh.DimEvents ON Dwh.DimEvents.devGuid = Dwh.FactTickets.ftEventGuid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Dwh.DimShows ON Dwh.DimEvents.devShowGuid = Dwh.DimShows.dshGuid
WHERE     (Dwh.FactTickets.ftTicketStatus = 1)
GROUP BY Dwh.DimClients.dcClientCode, Dwh.DimClients.dcFirstName, Dwh.DimClients.dcLastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. don't forget to test performance of the query..

```
SELECT  
(
Select MAX(DimEvents.devEventDate) 
from DimEvents INNER JOIN FactTickets ON DimEvents.devGuid = FactTickets.ftEventGuid 
and DimClients.dcClientGUID = FactTickets.ftClientGuid and DimEvents.devEventDate < GetDate() 
and FactTickets.ftTicketStatus = 1
) AS MostRecentPast,

(
Select MIN(DimEvents.devEventDate) 
from DimEvents INNER JOIN FactTickets ON DimEvents.devGuid = FactTickets.ftEventGuid 
and DimClients.dcClientGUID = FactTickets.ftClientGuid and DimEvents.devEventDate > GetDate() 
and FactTickets.ftTicketStatus = 1
) AS ClosestInFuture,
DimClients.dcClientCode, DimClients.dcFirstName, DimClients.dcLastName
FROM  DimClients 
GROUP BY DimClients.dcClientCode, DimClients.dcFirstName, DimClients.dcLastName
```

Comment: Hi Jawad, This didn't seem to work because it kept telling me that       'Dwh.FactTickets.ftEventGuid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  I tried adding in the Group By but then it just listed every event for every person

Comment: I don't think you need Group By at all because we have moved aggregate functions into sub-select. Can't test it here as I don't have complete database structure.

Comment: Sadly, although removing the Group By line allowed it to run, it still gives me all of the ticket dates rather than just the last and next.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dates for the most recent past ticket and nearest future ticket like so:

```
DECLARE @TargetDate datetime
SELECT @TargetDate = getdate()

SELECT MAX(TimeColumn) FROM table WHERE TimeColumn < @TargetDate

SELECT MIN(TimeColumn) FROM table WHERE TimeColumn > @TargetDate
```

You can then embed these as subqueries like so:

```
SELECT
   TicketColumn1,
   TicketColumn2,
   TicketColumn3,
   etc
FROM
   TicketTable
WHERE
   TimeColumn = ( SELECT MAX(TimeColumn) FROM table WHERE TimeColumn < @TargetDate )
   or TimeColumn = ( SELECT MIN(TimeColumn) FROM table WHERE TimeColumn > @TargetDate )
```